# Map xml string property to C# properties

Tags: c#, xml, automapper

I need to map a xml property to c# properties.

```
var src = new Source();
src.Id = 1;
src.Name = "Test";
src.Address = "<Country>MyCountry</Country><Prefecture>MyPrefecture</Prefecture><City>MyCity</City>";

class Source
{
public string ID{ get; set; }
public string Name{ get; set; }
public string Address{ get; set; }
}        

        Class Destination
        {
        public string ID{ get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set;}
        public string Prefecture { get; set;}
        public string City { get; set;}
        }
```

Is it possible to achieve it through AutoMapper?

Comment: Just use a standard xml reader, which will give you an object structure you can use to fetch values and populate your data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following. Considering your source type.

```
var src = new Source();
src.ID = 1;
src.Name = "Test";
src.Address = "<Country>MyCountry</Country><Prefecture>MyPrefecture</Prefecture><City>MyCity</City>";
```

Since your source type (src.Address) doesn't have a root element, let's add one and parse the xml to a XDocument.

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
xdoc = XDocument.Parse($"<Root>{src.Address}</Root>");
```

Now during Initializing of Automapper, you need to map fields.

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
           cfg.CreateMap<XElement, Destination>()
               .ForMember(dest => dest.Country, opt => opt.MapFrom(x=>x.Element(nameof(Destination.Country)).Value))
               .ForMember(dest => dest.City, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Element(nameof(Destination.City)).Value))
               .ForMember(dest => dest.Prefecture, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Element(nameof(Destination.Prefecture)).Value)));
```

Now you can resolve it as following.

```
 Destination result = Mapper.Map<XElement, Destination>(xdoc.Root);
```

**Update**

You can using ConstructUsing as well for the purpose, that would hide away the Xml related code away from your other codes.

```
var src = new Source();
src.ID = "1";
src.Name = "Test";
src.Address = "<Country>MyCountry</Country><Prefecture>MyPrefecture</Prefecture><City>MyCity</City>";

XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
xdoc = XDocument.Parse($"<Root>{src.Address}</Root>");

Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
                    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
                    .ConstructUsing(x=>ConstructDestination(x))
                 );
```

Where **ConstructDestination** is defined as

```
static Destination ConstructDestination(Source src)
{
   XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
   xdoc = XDocument.Parse($"<Root>{src.Address}</Root>");

   return new Destination
   {
     Country = xdoc.Root.Element(nameof(Destination.Country)).Value,
     City = xdoc.Root.Element(nameof(Destination.City)).Value,
     Prefecture = xdoc.Root.Element(nameof(Destination.Prefecture)).Value,
   };

 }
```

Your client code looks much cleaner now.

```
Destination result = Mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(src);
```

Comment: It Works. Thanks.

Comment: @Vignesh Glad it helped. Kindly mark it as answer if helped you resolve the issue.

Comment: I don't know whether this has changed, but I think `.ConstructUsing` should in fact be `.ConvertUsing`, otherwise the mapper tries to copy over the fields after construction has taken place using the provided function.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to wrap it with a root node and use a serializeable class.

The class would look like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class Address
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Prefecture { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize would looke like the following:

```
        string xml = "<Country>MyCountry</Country><Prefecture>MyPrefecture</Prefecture><City>MyCity</City>";
        string wrapped = $"<Address>{xml}</Address>";
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Address));
        Address addr = (Address)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(wrapped));
```