# Mapping IQueryable source with xml string property to IQueryable destination

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

In continuation to,
[Map xml string property to C# properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53661942/map-xml-string-property-to-c-sharp-properties/53663761?noredirect=1#comment94324142_53663761)

I have a IQueryable Source which needs to be mapped to the IQueryable Destination class along with the mapping of the xml string property.
I have tried using the below source but it doesn't work,

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
.ConstructUsing(x => ConstructDestination(x)));


static Destination ConstructDestination(Source src)
{
       XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
       xdoc = XDocument.Parse($"<Root>{src.Address}</Root>");

       return new Destination
       {
         Country = xdoc.Root.Element(nameof(Destination.Country)).Value,
         City = xdoc.Root.Element(nameof(Destination.City)).Value,
         Prefecture = xdoc.Root.Element(nameof(Destination.Prefecture)).Value,
       };

}

IQueryable<Destination> destQuery = srcQuery.ProjectTo<Destination>();
var result1 = destQuery.ToList();
```

Comment: Use Map instead, ProjectTo is for SQL queries.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu The actual case is for OData Query

Comment: Then you need expression mapping.